# Use of g key in vim normal mode

Tags: vim

In vim's normal mode, the `g` prefix is used for a number of commands. Some commands *go* somewhere in the document, but other commands deal with file encodings and swapping upper/lower case letters.

- `ga` - show character encoding
- `10gg` - go to line 10
- `gg` - go to line 1
- `gH` - start Select line mode
- `gr`{char} - virtual replace N chars with {char}

What is the missing connection between all these commands?

Comment: `g` and `z` extend the normal set of commands.

Comment: I always took both `g` and `z` as @Benoit: «`g{C}` was defined because it is a command that is commonly needed, but other characters are already binded». Many `g*` have a mnemonic `go to`/`global`, some not. Unlike `g*` `z*` commands that are not related to folds are harder to remember for me. I even personally in one of my plugins defined a set of `gd` mappings that can be memorized as `global diff`: «see all changes made by given revision». And near had a set of «go to» ones: `gu` - «go to user» - «view changes made by user» and so on.

Comment: The command to go to line 10 is `10gg` or `10G` (or `:10<cr>`).

Answer (score 68, accepted):

There's no greater connection to `g`-commands: it's a mixed bunch. It is an easy prefix and the unbound keys were getting extinct so the less-used maps found a good place behind `g`.

Comment: I noticed that some commands have mnemonics in Vim's help. For example, `ga` is `get ascii`

Comment: @NatanYellin: yes. Fortunately some commands under `g` are "go to" or "get" somethings but too many are without a good mnemonic.

Comment: @SauceMcBoss: I was just looking for the same. You can find it [the Vim documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/vimindex.html#g)

Answer (score 19):

Simply you're talking about two different things. In some cases g is the short way of "global" (for range command for example), for line moving the g stands for goto.

In VIM commands are often shortened for quick of use.

`:help global` may help

Btw: for line navigation I've always used the `:<lineno>` syntax.

Comment: `:<lineno>` spams command-line history and is harder to type (`<S-;>1<CR>`: four keypresses, two or three (dvorak) additional finger moves (effort used to type the number is ignored), `1gg`: three keypresses, one finger move). You can get rid of spamming  command-line history by defining some mapping (for example, mapping for `<CR>` in command-line mode that will clear history after executing command), but you can't make effort used to type this less.

Comment: oh well, try substituting <lineno> with a number and you'll get what I was trying to say ^^ :D. In the end is just a matter on how you started all. Coming from vanilla vi, some VIM intrinsics are totally obscure even after 10 years+ of happy vimming.

Comment: *«oh well, try substituting <lineno> with a number and you'll get what I was trying to say»*: «`<S-;>1<CR>`» above. I know this method, though usually saw it in an expressions like `execute linenumber`.

Comment: It's just a matter of how you learn it. Both ways have their pros and cons. In the end as long as we're confortable with 'em, is good. Forgive my real bad English.